# objectlistview background color changes to black

Tags: winforms, objectlistview

I am using winforms and version 2.7.0 of OLV.  I've noticed what seems to be a paint issue with the control.  My title reads "background color changes to black", but really the entire control show as black at certain times.  I have this control sitting on a form with plenty of other controls and they don't exhibit this behavior. This issue seems to be tied to the form becoming non-responsive.  I make webservice calls from this application, and there are times when these calls do not complete timely.  In these cases, my application will temporarily become unresponsive.  Usually, a very short amount of time (2 or 3 seconds) and I see (Not Responding) text in the title bar.  When this happens the area taken by the OLV control turns black.  If anyone else has seen this, I would like to know if there is some setting I might need to change.  NOTE: there are no other windows on top of my form.  Some designer code below

```
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.AllColumns.Add(this.olvColFileName);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.AllColumns.Add(this.olvColCancelButton);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.olvColFileName,
        this.olvColCancelButton});
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.EmptyListMsg = "";
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.EmptyListMsgFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.HeaderUsesThemes = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.HideSelection = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 10);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.MultiSelect = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Name = "objListView_EvidenceFiles";
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.SelectAllOnControlA = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.SelectColumnsOnRightClick = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.SelectColumnsOnRightClickBehaviour = BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.ColumnSelectBehaviour.None;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.ShowGroups = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.ShowItemToolTips = true;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 238);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.SmallImageList = this.imageList_Icons;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.TabIndex = 1;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.TabStop = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.UnfocusedHighlightBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.UnfocusedHighlightForegroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.CellClick += new System.EventHandler<BrightIdeasSoftware.CellClickEventArgs>(this.objListView_EvidenceFiles_CellClick);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.objListView_EvidenceFiles_SelectionChanged);
        this.objListView_EvidenceFiles.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.objListView_EvidenceFiles_Leave);
```

I have a screenshot of our app (some items I don't wish to expose are cleared):
[image]

Comment: I have never seen that problem before but I would try to reset the OLV using *ClearObjects*, *AddObjects*, and *BuildList* on a crash or the moment when this happens.

Comment: @BarryGuvenkaya, I probably did not explain this detail well enough, but the control does not crash.  The black shows temporarily.  When the form becomes responsive again, the control comes back to life and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked the ObjectListView as OwnerDrawn, so Windows will send messages to the control when it needs to redraw it. Underneath, Window will have cleared the controls display buffer, waiting for the control to render itself, but the control can't because you have basically hung your application during those 2 or 3 seconds. The redraw messages will have been queued, and will be process as soon as you application starts working again.

Best solution: don't hang your app! Move the long running task onto a background thread, and update the UI when the background fetch has finished. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107258/objectlistview-elapsed-time-column-potentially-needs-multi-threading/26113357#26113357).